# reusable wrapper for fixed and full width page

Tags: html, css

I have one wrapper which is fixed width for all of my pages, but what if i have a page with a content that needs to have a full width like for example slideshow.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
//fixed width contents
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper{
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I don't want to create another wrapper with full width like:

**CSS**

```
#wrapper-full-width{
width: 100%
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id='wrapper-full-width'>
// some contents with full width like slideshow
</div>
```

So i only need one wrapper which i can use for all my pages.

**HOMEPAGE**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header"></div>

<div id="slideshow> // fixed width=960px</div>

<div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

**PRODUCT PAGE**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header"></div>

<div id="slideshow"> // full width=100% </div>

<div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

How can i use same wrapper for pages with contents that need to have a full width?

Comment: Would it be possible to add a class to `div#slideshow` or `div#wrapper` on the the pages you need a full width slideshow? Because you cannot select elements based on "the page" (for example url) in CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's two option: either add a class of `fullwidth` to the wrapper itself or to the `<body>` tag on that specific page:

```
<div id="wrapper" class="fullwidth">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="slideshow"></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

```css
#wrapper.fullwidth { width: 100%; }
```

Or:

```
<body class="fullwidth">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="header"></div>
      <div id="slideshow"></div>
      <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```css
.fullwidth #wrapper { width: 100%; }
```